# How can I simulate a right-click in Kubuntu 10.10 when using a touchscreen?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, touchscreen

i am running Kubuntu 10.10 on my WeTab Tablet PC.
As this Tablet has no mouse (but a touchscreen), I would like to configure Kubuntu in a way that allows to perform a right-click.

In Ubuntu (not Kubuntu), there is an option to just hold the left-click for about 3 seconds in order to perform a right-click (Mouse => Accessibility => "Trigger secondary click by holding down the primary button").

I can't find something similar in Kubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked under System Settings > Input Devices > Touchpad (Tapping tab)?

I don't have a table PC but my laptop has a touchpad that gives options to make parts of the pad behave as a button.

Comment: thanks for your help, Dirk, but unfortunately, this field is all grey. I have no chance to do some settings there... :(

Comment: :( thats sorry, maybe look for a app that can give you this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it looks like this is only available for a Unity/Gtk/Gnome based desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find any solution, you may use ["Menu Key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) in a onscreen keyboard like "Kvkbd" or "Onboard".